# Colorbar placement in cartopy

Tags: python, colorbar, cartopy

**Aim:** I'd like to move the colorbar from the right hand side to the bottom as in the following picture.

[image: wanted result]

In my case, matplotlib's colorbar orientation keyword seems to be ignored when cartopy is used. The picture below is the result of my code at the end of my question.

[image: current result]

**Question:**

How do I need to adapt my code so the colorbar will appear below the plot as in the first picture?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 12), facecolor='white')
cmap = 'Blues_r'

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

sm = ax.pcolormesh(longitudes, latitudes, data, cmap=cmap, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()

ax.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LatitudeFormatter())

### COLORBAR ###
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.1, axes_class=plt.Axes)

fig.add_axes(cax)
cb = plt.colorbar(sm, label=r"Cloud Fraction [%]", cax=cax, orientation = "horizontal", extend='max', shrink=0.5)

# add a horizontal line to the colorbar axis
cb.ax.vlines(np.nanmean(data), cb.vmin, cb.vmax, label="Mean", colors= "yellow", linestyles='solid', linewidth=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Update:**

A work around would be the following:

Delete the `divider`, `cax` and `fig.add` in the above code section and run only the two lines below:

```
cb = fig.colorbar(sm, label=r"Cloud Fraction [%]", extend='max', orientation="horizontal", shrink=0.5, pad=0.05)

cb.ax.vlines(np.nanmean(data), cb.vmin, cb.vmax, label="Mean", colors="yellow", linestyles='solid', linewidth=12)
```

Comment: FYI: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html

Answer (score 0):

Your update is good. One thing I used before is this that may be helpful for you in the future.

```
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.08, 0.1, 0.86, 0.04]) 
cb=plt.colorbar(cax=cbaxes, orientation='horizontal',drawedges=True)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=6,direction="in")        
cb.set_label("CH4 Concentration (ppm)",fontsize=6, rotation=0)
```

The first line allows be to define the colorbar size how I would like. The dimensions go as [left, bottom, width, height].

You already know what the second line does but I like to write drawedges=True because it puts the lines in between each color and allow you to see the different colors better.

The label line just gives you the title. [Here is an example of what the colorbar would turn into.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdGxi.png)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also let matplotlib create the `cax` for you, in my experience the result is usually good. I would only ceate the `cax` myself if I needed something really specific.

Replace this:

```py
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.1, axes_class=plt.Axes)

fig.add_axes(cax)
cb = plt.colorbar(
    sm, label=r"Cloud Fraction [%]", cax=cax, 
    orientation="horizontal", extend='max', ,
    shrink=0.5,
)
```

With:

```py
cb = fig.colorbar(
    sm, ax=ax, label=r"Cloud Fraction [%]", shrink=0.5,
    orientation="horizontal", extend='max', 
)
```